# Bash script - Output of find to here-string (<<<)

Tags: bash, sftp

Line in my script trying to get the output of find to be in the here-string but I keep getting "put {}" with the obvious "{}: No such file or directory"

```
find "$SOURCE_DIR" -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sshpass -p "$PASSWORD" sftp -oPort=$PORT $USER@$HOST:$HOST_DIR <<< $'put' {} 2>&1 \;
```

How to I pass the filename into the here-string so that sftp will put the file?

My previous line in the script was this which I had no problems with. However, I can no longer use curl in this script.

```
find "$SOURCE_DIR" -type f -name "*.txt" -exec curl -T {} sftp://$USER:$PASSWORD@$HOST:$PORT$HOST_DIR 2>&1 \;
```

Comment: `<<<` is shell syntax. It doesn't happen once per `-exec`, because `find -exec` doesn't start at a shell; it only happens once _total_

Comment: Also, `foo <<<"something" other-arg` is exactly the same as `foo other-arg <<<"something"`; putting the `{}` after the `<<<"something"` doesn't make it part of the herestring's contents.

Comment: And all-caps variable names are reserved; you should be using lowercase names for `password`, `user`, `host`, `host_dir`; see the relevant POSIX standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and regular shell variables share a single namespace (setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable).

Comment: BTW, `sshpass -p` is a _really_ bad idea; it makes your password readable by every user on the same machine, even completely untrusted accounts like `nobody`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I don't write many bash scripts so I appreciate the info. I'll be sure to update my script accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find -exec` doesn't implicitly start a shell, so it doesn't run shell operations or redirections.

You *could* make it start a shell (this is discussed in [the *Complex Actions* section of Using Find](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Complex_actions)), but it's just as easy to write a NUL-delimited list of filenames, and read them into your shell:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file <&3; do
  sshpass -p "$PASSWORD" sftp -oPort="$PORT" "$USER@$HOST:$HOST_DIR" <<<"put $file"
done 3< <(find "$SOURCE_DIR" -type f -name "*.txt" -print0)
```

As an additional optimization, think about only running `sftp` *once*, not once per file (note that this is using the GNU `-printf` extension to `find`):

```
find "$SOURCE_DIR" -type f -name "*.txt" -printf 'put %p\n' |
  sshpass -p "$PASSWORD" sftp -oPort="$PORT" "$USER@$HOST:$HOST_DIR"
```